# Why codecvt can't convert unicode outside BMP to u16string?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to understand C++ unicode and having this confused me now.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
using namespace std;

void trial1(){
    string a = "\U00010000z";
    cout << a << endl;
    u16string b;
    std::wstring_convert<codecvt_utf8<char16_t>, char16_t> converter;
    b = converter.from_bytes(a);
    u16string c = b.substr(0, 1);
    string q = converter.to_bytes(c);
    cout << q << endl;
}

void trial2(){
    u16string a = u"\U00010000";
    cout << a.length() << endl; // 2
    std::wstring_convert<codecvt_utf8<char16_t>, char16_t> converter;
    string b = converter.to_bytes(a);
}

int main() {
//    both don't work
//    trial1();
//    trial2();
    return 0;
}
```

I have tested that `u16string` can store unicode outside BMP as surrogate pairs, e.g. `u"\U00010000"` is stored with 2 `char16_t`.

So why `std::wstring_convert<codecvt_utf8<char16_t>, char16_t> converter;` doesn't work for both `trial1` and `trial2` and throw an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::codecvt_utf8` does not support conversions to/from UTF-16, only UCS-2 and UTF-32.  You need to use [`std::codecvt_utf8_utf16`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8_utf16) instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I didn't know there's `codecvt_utf8_utf16`. C++ is so hard